# Is localhost the same domain as /var/www/ on Apache?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, xmlhttprequest

I've been trying to get a clear answer on this all afternoon and the internet isn't helping much.

I have a html page that submits a form to a php script using `XMLHttpRequest` but I am receiving an empty `responseText`.

I've tested the code and I now believe it has something to do with the Same Origin Policy. But if both scripts are saved in the same folder (/var/www/), how can they not be of the same origin? (I'm probably missing something simple.)

(Specs: Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3, testing in Firefox)

Thanks!

Comment: How does the headers of the response looks like?

Comment: Are they both running on `localhost` or are you accessing one directly from `/var/www/`? Your webserver may host files from `/var/www/`, but `/var/www/` is just a folder and it isn't the same as `localhost`.

Comment: Did you configure Apache?  Either `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache/*` depending on the Linux distribution.

Comment: You mean `http://localhost` vs `file:///var/www` ?

Comment: @ Blender - Ah success!!! I was opening the html file in the folder by right-clicking, so the address bar in Firefox read "file:///var/www/myHTMLFile.html". I changed the address to "http://localhost/myHTMLFile.html" and it works like a charm!   >.<  Such a stupid mistake on my part but I guess that's part of learning. If you want to post it as an answer I'll except it. Thanks!!

Comment: how is this a javascript question

Comment: @ama2 - the javascript tag was in reference to the `XMLHttpRequest`... I probably should have left the javascript tag off.